# "I hope that my search ends now" or "I hope my search ends now"?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, that

I was doing a question for Yahoo Answers and suddenly I can't choice.
Maybe because I never study English(after elementary and high school), I don't know which is the right sentence?

Of course I know that I should study, and I'll do.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Either expression is fine.

> After I Googled several different sets of words, I hit "enter" and said to myself, "I hope that my search ends now!"

Or,

> After Googling numerous combinations of words, I hit "enter" and said out loud, "I hope my search ends now."